# Problematic duality argument in Lp space

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

I am confused with the following argument concerning dual spaces of Lebesgue spaces.
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded measurable set and consider
$L^p = L^p(\Omega)$ for $p \geq 1$.
We know the dual $(L^p)^*$ of $L^p$ space is identified with $L^{p'}$ when $1 \leq p < \infty$.

For simplicity, consider $L^3$ so that $L^3 \subset L^2$ and $L^2 = (L^2)^* \subset (L^3)^*$.

Let $T \in (L^3)^*$. By Hahn-Banach extension theorem, there exists $\tilde T \in (L^2)^*$ such that
$\tilde T \restriction_{L^3} = T$, and by Riesz' representation theorem, there exists a unique $f \in L^2$ such that
$\tilde T(g) = \int_{\Omega} f(x) g(x) \,dx$ for all $g \in L^2$.

Hence, for all $g \in L^3$, we have

\begin{equation*}
  T(g) = \tilde T(g) = \int_{\Omega} f(x) g(x) \,dx.
\end{equation*}

This means $(L^3)^* \subset L^2$ and hence $(L^3)^* = L^2$.
But in this is argument, there must be a mistake since $(L^3)^* = L^{3/2}$,
though, I do not know what is wrong.

Please any help.

Comment: “$(L^3)^* \subset L^2$ and hence $(L^3)^* = L^2$.” why is this step?

Comment: By Riesz' representation theorem, $L^2 = (L^2)^* \subset (L^3)^*$. Above wrong arugment says $(L^3)^* \subset L^2$. Hence I think $(L^3)^* = L^2$.

Comment: Since $L^2$ is a proper subspace of $L^{3/2}=(L^3)^*$, we can plug in a function in $L^{3/2}\setminus L^2$ and check which step is wrong

Comment: e.g. $x^{-1/2}$ for $\Omega=[0,1],n=1$

Comment: Yes, $f(x) = x^{-1/2} \in L^{3/2} \setminus L^2$ when $\Omega = [0,1]$.
Is it a problem that I conclude that $(L^3)^* \subset L^2$ from $T(g) = \tilde T(g)$ for all $g \in L^3$?

Comment: Yes, that step should be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I understand which step is wrong, it is the Hahn-Banach extension theorem.

For simplicity, let us consider $n=1$ and $\Omega = [0,1]$.
Then, the linear functional $T$ on $L^3$ defined by

$$T(g) = \int_{\Omega} x^{-1/2} g(x) \,dx, \quad g \in L^3$$

is continuous on $(L^3, \| \cdot \|_{L^3})$, but not continuous on $(L^3, \| \cdot \|_{L^2})$.
Hence, the Hahn-Banach extension theorem is not applicable.